# Get data fork size through C/C++ without using deprecated FSCatalogInfo's dataLogicalSize field

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I am working on removing the use of deprecated Carbon based API's in my application. I am unable to find a method to calculate the data fork size in C++ without using the deprecated FSCatalogInfo struct's dataLogicalSize.
I found out that the keys available in NS File Manager based methods, return size without taking data fork size in account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`-[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410452-attributesofitematpath?language=objc) will return a dictionary containing the key `NSFileSize` (among others) with a value equivalent to the `dataLogicalSize` you're looking for. The size of any resource fork present on the file is not included -- I've specifically verified this against several old files with resource forks I had lying around. :)

As a practical matter, files you will encounter in modern macOS systems will virtually never have resource forks.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I also found `fileSize` method which returns the same.